# Is there a way to collect the multiple power into a single power?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I am looking away to factor perfect powers like follows:

`FactorPerfectPower[16x^2]` should produce `Inactive[Power][4x,2]`.

`FactorPerfectPower[7x^2]` should produce `7x^2`.

`FactorPerfectPower[91125x^18y^6]` should produce `Inactive[Power][45x^6y^2,3]`

What is the simplest and efficient way to do this?

Comment: I haven't worked it out yet, but am working with a combination of ```FullForm```, ```FactorInteger``` and ```GCD```.  Have to pause for a bit but will revisit.

Comment: @MarkR I've got a solution but don't want to take away the opportunity for you to answer! :) how's it coming? (or should I post mine?)

Comment: @MarkR ok, since it's been a day I'm going to post my answer later today

Comment: whoops, forgot! ok, posted :)

Comment: and updated to handle negative bases :)

Comment: @thorimur - thank you for posting!   I was sidetracked and  doubt that I would have come up with such a nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends in part on whether by "simplest" you mean "most readable" or "shortest". I'll assume the first, but let me know if you're interested in the second.

Definitions in Mathematica are pretty fast: as I understand it, Mathematica creates a dispatch table of the replacement rules you define, which is optimized. Simple pattern matching (especially when not using variable-length pattern like `__`) is generally faster than the corresponding `Switch` or `If` statements, too, I think.

Here we'll take the following strategy:

1. Define `GetPower[x]` to obtain the highest perfect power in its argument.
2. Define `GetRoot[p][x]` to get the `p`th root of its argument. We need this because without special assumptions, `(x^n)^(1/p)` does not evaluate to `x^(n/p)`.
3. Define `FactorPerfectPower` directly for simple terms, and define it to use the largest common divisor of the powers when given a product (i.e. something with head `Times`. (Note that we don't have to worry about terms of the form `(Times[...])^n)`, since Mathematica automatically distributes the power.)

We'll also make it work on combinations of previously-power-factored terms, e.g. `FactorPerfectPower[Inactive[Power][x,6] Inactive[Power[y,4]]` should yield `Inactive[Power][x^3 y^2, 2]`.

We also need to take care to check if the power is `1`, in which case we don't want to wrap it in an `Inactive[Power]`, as e.g. `Inactive[Power][x,1]`. (Though there would be some merit to doing this, and it makes some things a bit nicer: for instance, it tells you whether or not a term has already been power-factored (assuming `Inactive[Power]` isn't used for anything else.))

```
ClearAll[GetPower, GetRoot, FactorPerfectPower]

(* GetPower *)

(* Note: we only recognize integral powers. We could extend this to
   rational numbers and symbols with some work. *)

GetPower[n_Integer?NonNegative] := GCD @@ Last /@ FactorInteger[n]

GetPower[(Power | Inactive[Power])[x_, n_Integer]] := n

GetPower[x_] := 1

(* GetRoot *)

GetRoot[p_][n_Integer?NonNegative] := n^(1/p)

GetRoot[p_][(Power | Inactive[Power])[x_, n_]] := Power[x, n/p]

(* FactorPerfectPower *)

FactorPerfectPower[n_Integer] := With[{p = GCD @ GetPower[n]},
 If[p === 1, n, Inactive[Power][GetRoot[p][n], p]]]

FactorPerfectPower[Power[x_, n_Integer]] := Inactive[Power][x, n]

FactorPerfectPower[product_Times] :=
 With[{terms = List @@ product},
  With[{gcd = GCD @@ GetPower /@ terms}, 
   If[gcd === 1, Activate[product, Power], 
    Inactive[Power][Times @@ GetRoot[gcd] /@ terms, gcd]]]]

FactorPerfectPower[x_] := x

(* Tests: *)

FactorPerfectPower[16 x^2]

FactorPerfectPower[7x^2]

FactorPerfectPower[91125x^18y^6]

FactorPerfectPower[FactorPerfectPower[x^6] FactorPerfectPower[y^4]]
```

Let me know if this works the way you want or if you have any questions on how it works!

(Note that we use `Activate[product, Power]` in the definition for products. This is nice to read, but ever so slightly risky, as we activate all `Power`'s inside the product, even ones buried deep inside terms, which are possibly `Inactive` for different reasons. A more careful implementation might use `Replace[product, Inactive[Power][x_, n_] :> Power[x, n], {1}]`.)

---

There's another approach worth mentioning: getting rid of `GetRoot` and `GetPower` and only use definitions for `FactorPerfectPower`: for products, we map `FactorPerfectPower` over the terms in the product, then extract their power from the results to recombine them. Cost: both simplicity in the definition for products and some efficiency, as we wind up taking roots we don't need to sometimes, and wind up replicating `GetRoot` and `GetPower` in the function body anyway.

---

There is something I haven't figured out yet: dealing with minus signs, e.g. `FactorPerfectPower[-x^3]` (which could be reasonably expected to return `Inactive[Power][-x,3]`). I'll keep you posted. :)

**EDIT:** Okay, here's my attempt. There's a deeper way to deal with general roots of unity here, but for now, here's a particular solution for negatives.

We use the fact that for any odd number $p$, $(-1)^p=-1$. In a sense, the power of $-1$ in a prime factorization of some $n<0$ is "all odd numbers". The "greatest common divisor" of "any odd number" with some positive integer $k$ is essentially the largest odd factor of $k$.

To mimic this, we'll define a special symbol `odds` representing the power of $-1$ in the factorization of a negative number. We'll give it the desired behavior described above under `GCD` as an upvalue, and define the function `RemoveEven` to get the largest odd factor of the remaining `GCD` (though maybe there's a built-in that essentially accomplishes this small task, I'm not sure).

Note that `GCD[]` is `0`, but the largest odd factor of `odds` should be `1`, so `GCD[odds] ==> RemoveEven @ GCD[]` means that `RemoveEven[0]` should be `1`.

I've modified the definitions in the original a little so that they only apply to positive integers, and thus don't conflict with these.

(*Later edit:*) We also needed to make one significant change to `FactorPerfectPower[n_Integer]` to make `FactorPerfectPower[-1]` work: instead of using `p = GetPower[n]`, we needed to use `p = GCD @ GetPower[n]`. This has no effect when the result of `GetPower` is integral, but since we're using a special symbol `odds`, we need to choose a particular power via `GCD`. (If we were to make this even more general, I suspect we'd need to use this on other instances of `GetPower` as well, where we did not have `GCD @ GetPower[x]` yielding `1`.)

```
ClearAll[RemoveEven, odds]

(* RemoveEven *)
(* There are many other ways of doing this, e.g. something like
   NestWhile[#/2 &, n, EvenQ]. This one has a nice meaning, though. *)

RemoveEven[n_Integer?EvenQ] := 
 Times @@ Power @@@ DeleteCases[FactorInteger[n], {2|0, _}]

RemoveEven[n_] := n

(* odds *)

odds /: GCD[args0___, odds, args1___] := RemoveEven @ GCD[args0, args1]

(* Modify GetPower and GetRoot approriately *)

GetPower[-1] = odds;

GetPower[n_Integer?Negative] := 
 GCD @@ Last /@ 
   Replace[FactorInteger[n], {-1, _} -> {-1, GetPower[-1]}, {1}]


GetRoot[p_Integer?OddQ][n_Integer?Negative] := -(-n)^(1/p)

(* Tests: *)

FactorPerfectPower[-1]

FactorPerfectPower[-27]

FactorPerfectPower[-27 x^3]

FactorPerfectPower[-x^3]
```

Since `FactorPerfectPower` relies entirely on `GetPower`, `GetRoot`, and `GCD`, we don't need to modify it at all. But note that I did have to modify the original block to make it less general, and to use explicit reliance on `GetRoot` where I hadn't before. Future iterations might require the same.

Note that Mathematica never uses `Minus`, even though it has it as an operation; `-expr` is parsed as `Times[-1, expr]`. This is why the last test expression didn't need any special attention.