# Why is Log not acting as an inverse of Power function?

Tags: inverse-function

I know `-8 = Power[-8,1] or Power[-2,3]` so when I evaluate:

```
Log[-8,-8]
```

I get `1` as expected but when I evaluate

```
Log[-2,-8]
```

I am not getting `3` as the answer. Is there a way to get `3` as the answer?

```
Power[-2,Log[-2,-8]]
```

does produce `-8` so it is a correct solution but not the real one. Why is `Log[-2,-8]` not giving the obvious real one instead of taking its journey into the complex plane?

Comment: in general, the reasoning is because to have `Log` be differentiable on most of the complex plane, you need to choose a branch. an easy branch is one which omits flips on a straight ray in the complex plane from 0 out to $-\infty$. With any straight-ray branch, though, there's no branch such that `Log[-2,(-2)^n]` gives `n` for all `n`, I don't think. Also, logs with negative bases are even trickier! But, motivation on the Mathematica end aside:

Comment: What would you like in a solution? Something that redefines `Log`, or something custom that gives the appropriate answer for integers when available? If the latter, check out my answer for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255492/is-there-a-way-to-collect-the-multiple-power-into-a-single-power), or lmk why it doesn't work here! (EDIT: oh wait! that's your question! lol. Well, lmk if you'd like something for this case anyway, bc i think it could be adapted, and it's a cool question )

Comment: @thorimur something like `RealValuedLog[...]` that gives the appropriate answer if a real value exists and `Indeterminate` otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

#### An initial attempt

Here's one quick way to do that:

```
RealValuedLog[b_, x_] := 
 Module[{n, r}, 
  r = Solve[b^n == x, n \[Element] Reals];
  If[MatchQ[r, {{n -> _}, ___}], n /. First@r, Indeterminate]]
```

(We store the result in an intermediate variable `r` so that we don't have to `Solve` twice.)

This will give you *a* solution, but some work would need to be done to make sure it gives some sort of "canonical" solution, and to handle `0`, `1`, `-1` cases.

---

#### Edge case definitions

Here are some definitions to add to `RealValuedLog` to make it behave well in the edge cases.

In the following, we'll take by convention that

- `RealValuedLog[0, x]` is `1` if `x == 0` and `Indeterminate` otherwise
- `RealValuedLog[b, 0]` is `Indeterminate` unless `b` is `0`.
- `RealValuedLog[1, x]` is `0` if `x == 1` and `Indeterminate` otherwise
- `RealValuedLog[u, x]` for `u != 1` on the unit circle is `Log[u, x]` if `x` is also on the unit circle (which is the ratio of their (complex-plane) arguments as per Mathematica's standard branch cut) and `Indeterminate` otherwise

(I think `RealValuedLog[0,1]` should be `0`, and I think `0^0` should be `1`, but Mathematica disagrees, so we'll leave it `Indeterminate` in order to provide an inverse to `Power`...)

```
RealValuedLog[_?(EqualTo[0]), x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x == 0}}, Indeterminate]

RealValuedLog[_, _?(EqualTo[0])] := Indeterminate

RealValuedLog[_?(EqualTo[1]), x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x == 1}}, Indeterminate]

RealValuedLog[b_ /; Abs[b] == 1, x_] :=
  Piecewise[{{Log[b, x], Abs[x] == 1}}, Indeterminate]
```

The ordering of definitions is important to be preserved as-is here to make sure `RealValuedLog[0,0]` is `1` and not `Indeterminate`. (We could fix this fragility by using `_?(Not@*EqualTo[0])` if we wanted to.)

The use of `Piecewise` is meant to give you some power when using symbolic arguments for `x`, but of course it could easily have been written any other way.

Also note that we use `_?(EqualTo[0])` instead of `0` for numeric reasons: `MatchQ[0, 0.]` is `False`.

---

#### A definition without `Reduce`

There is also a more direct way to define the main body of the function.

*Background:* in order to define $b^y$ for complex $b$ and real $y$, we need to choose a way to assign an argument to $b$, i.e. a value $\theta(b)$ such that $b = |b|e^{i\theta(b)}$. Then for real $y$ we can define define $b^y = |b|^y e^{i \theta(b)y}$. But for any such choice of $\theta(b)$, we also have that $\theta(b) + n 2 \pi$ would be a valid choice too for $n$ any integer, as $e^{2\pi i n} = 1$.

(When exponentiating with integers, there's no problem: $b^k = |b|^k e^{i k \theta(b)} = |b|^k e^{i k \theta(b) + 2 \pi i k n}$ for all integers $n$, as $kn$ is always integral if $k$ and $n$ are. But when $k$ is an arbitrary real number, we might end up with a nonintegral multiple of $2\pi i$, which would contribute a nontrivial phase.)

But let's just take $\theta(b)$ to be given by the standard branch cut, which coincides with Mathematica's `Arg[b]`, and take $b^y = |b|^y e^{i \theta(b) y}$ as Mathematica does.

We're interested in whether $b^y = x$ for any value of $y$. We can extract info from the absolute value: taking the absolute value of both sides, we require $|b|^y = |x|$. So if $y$ is anything, it's $\log_{|b|}|x|$, which is well-defined if $0 < |b|$, $|b| \neq 1$, and $|x| > 0$ (which we're assuming it is, as we still need the special cases). But does this make the phases work? Now that we have the only candidate for $y$, we need to check that $|b|^ye^{i \theta(b)y} = |x|e^{i\theta(x)}$. This is true iff $\theta(b)y \equiv \theta(x) \mod 2\pi$. Given that, we have a solution; otherwise it's indeterminate. So instead of our `Reduce` definition, we can use:

```
(* Equivalent main body definition; still requires special cases *)

RealValuedLog[b_, x_] :=
 With[{log = Log[Abs[b], Abs[x]]},
  Piecewise[{{log, Mod[Arg[b]*log - Arg[x], 2 Pi] == 0}}, Indeterminate]]
```

Note that we still need the special cases, lest we encounter `ComplexInfinity` or uninformative values like `Log[1,1]` when dealing with two different points on the unit circle.

---

#### Better handling of non-numeric arguments

A more symbolic (in both variables instead of just the latter) (but less readable and efficient) version of this function might stick the whole thing in an even larger `Piecewise` that contains all of the different `b` cases so that Mathematica has a chance of reasoning about it:

```
(* Additional definition to deal with nonnumeric first arguments *)

RealValuedLog[b_?(Not@*NumericQ), x_] :=
 Piecewise[{
   {1, b == 0 && x == 0},
   {0, b == 1 && x == 1},
   {Log[b,x], b != 1 && Abs[b] == 1 && Abs[x] == 1},
   {Log[Abs[b], Abs[x]], b != 0 && x != 0 && Abs[b] != 1
     && Mod[Arg[b]*Log[Abs[b], Abs[x]] - Arg[x], 2 Pi] == 0}},
  Indeterminate]
```

I use `b_?(Not@*NumericQ)` so you can add this in if you want. If I were doing it from scratch, I would have used `b_?NumericQ` in the other definition and `b_` in this one, or maybe even just sacrificed readability and gone with a more-commented version of this definition with `b_, x_` alone.

Comment: By the way, the question was 'why' not 'how'....

Comment: @yarchik If you read the comments on the original, you'll see that I attempted to answer why, and then asked OP what they wanted in a solution. They said they wanted something like `RealValuedLog`.